# NSPredicate fetch based on the count found in relationship

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I have a **User** Class and **UserType** Class.

User Entity Structure and UserType Structure is listed below.

[image]

UserTypes.Type can be employee, student or any other thing.

```
NSFetchRequest *userRequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];



NSSortDescriptor *sortByName=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];



[req setSortDescriptors:@[sortByName]];

userFetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:userRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"newRelationshilp.type" cacheName:nil];

[userFetchController performFetch:nil];
```

Now, if the Employee type wants only 5 results it should fetch first 5. If the "Student" type wants only 1 , it should only fetch the first one. So, in short, the showNumberOfEntries should be considered as limit for every type that is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

For solving of you're problem you should use [fetchLimit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-BAJBEABG) of the `NSFetchRequest`

```
[userRequest setFetchLimit:5];
```